# morphism between projective spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Why there is not nonconstant morphism from $P^{n}$ to $P^{1}$ when $ n>1$, and how about the case when we replace the $P^{1}$ by an arbitary projective curve $C$?

Another one: Let $C\subset P^{3}$ be a non-singular rational curve and $H$ be a hypersurface of degree two. How many points in the intersedtion set $C\bigcap H$?

Comment: A morphism $P^n\to P^1$ would be given by two homogeneous polynomials $f_0,f_1$, but these have a common zero if $n>1$..

Comment: For the last question, the number of intersection points could be arbitrarily large, if the degree of $C$ is large.

Comment: A slight variation on J.C Ottem's answer, for an arbitrary curve C: any fibre of such a morphism would have to have dimension n-1, i.e. be a hypersurface in P^n (see Shafarevich Ch.1 for a proof). But any two hypersurfaces in P^n intersect if n>1.

Answer (score 5):

There are no holomorphic maps from a projective space to a Kahler 
manifold X of smaller dimension. Indeed, the pullback of a Kahler form
$\omega_X$ cannot be exact, because a positive closed form, integrated with an
appropriate power of a Kahler form, is non-zero. Since the Picard group of
P^n is Z, a pullback of a Kahler class is a Kahler class. However,
$\omega_X^{dim X+1}=0$ downstairs, and upstairs it is non-zero
because the cohomology algebra of P^n is truncated polynomials.

Such X is automatically Kahler, but it would take
some effort to prove.

Answer (score 3):

**Geometric proof**:
For $\mathbf{P}^n \to \mathbf{P}^1$: Do you know the theorem on morphisms to projective space, [Hartshorne], Theorem II.7.1? Alternatively, one could use the "Projective Dimension Theorem", [Hartshorne], Theorem I.7.2.

For $\mathbf{P}^1 \to C$: Use the Hurwitz formula, [Hartshorne], Corollary IV.2.4.

For $\mathbf{P}^n \to C$: There is a $k = 2$ or $3$ such that there exists a closed immersion $C \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}^k$. Similarly to the above, there are no non-constant morphisms $\mathbf{P}^n \to \mathbf{P}^k$ for $n > k$.

**Cohomological proof**:
Alternatively: If $f: X \to Y$ is surjective, $f^\ast: H^\ast(Y) \hookrightarrow H^\ast(X)$ is injective for a Weil cohomology theory $H^\ast(-)$. For $\ell$-adic cohomology, $H^*_\ell(\mathbf{P}^n)$ can be easily calculated: $H_\ell^{2i}(\mathbf{P}^n_{\bar{k}}) = \mathbf{Q}_\ell$ for $i = 0, 1, \ldots, n$, and the other cohomology groups are $0$; and $H^1_\ell(C_{\bar{k}}) = \mathbf{Q}_\ell^{2g}$, $g$ the genus of $C$.

For the last question: [Hartshorne], Theorem I.7.7.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: The following statement is very false: "If $f \colon X \to Y$ is surjective, $f^\ast \colon H^\ast(Y) \hookrightarrow H^\ast(X)$ is injective". Consider $Y$ a nodal cubic and $X$ its normalization.